# How can I modify this perfect code for my own code?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, gif

I have this perfect Python Pillow Code that **edits each frame of a GIF file** with some colors and saves it

```
def process_image(filename, color_depth):
    original = Image.open(filename)

    new = []
    for frame_num in range(original.n_frames):
        original.seek(frame_num)
        new_frame = Image.new('RGBA', original.size)
        new_frame.paste(original)
        new_frame = new_frame.convert(mode='P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=color_depth)
        new.append(new_frame)

 

    new[0].save('Images/new.gif', append_images=new[1:], save_all=True, loop=0)
```

And I have this code that edits a **single image** and adds a watermark on it

```
def Image_Watermark(directory, filename):
    #Opening Image & Creating New Text Layer
    img = Image.open(directory + "/" + filename).convert("RGBA")
    txt = Image.new('RGBA', img.size, (255,255,255,0))

    #Creating Text
    text = "WATERMARK EXAMPLE"
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 27)

    #Creating Draw Object
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)

    #Positioning of Text
    width, height = img.size
    # textwidth, textheight = d.textsize(text, font)
    # x=width/2-textwidth/2
    # y=height-textheight-300

    # Loop for Multiple Watermarks
    y=200
    for i in range(7):
        x=random.randint(0, width-300)
        y+=random.randrange(0,int(height/8), 19)+random.randint(0,100)
        draw.text((x,y), text, fill=(255,255,255, 75), font=font)

    #Combining both layers and saving new image
    watermarked = Image.alpha_composite(img, txt)
    watermarked.save(filename)
```

Now the first **code edits the gifs perfectly** but **i dont want that color change**, instead i want what the second code does, **adding a watermark**, to each frame of the gif and save it.

It seems like a simple combination of both codes that I need to do but I cant figure out how, could someone help me out on how to get this done?

Thanks!

Comment: You've got all the building blocks there. Give it a go. If you get stuck, feel free to come back with a _specific_ question about the code you are using.

Comment: You don't need to understand every single thing. Can you figure out how the first snippet iterates over the frames in the GIF? How would you change what it does to each frame?

Comment: The solution should be something like "Delete these lines, and put in the function "Image_Watermark" here. So it can loop and edit trough each frame"

Comment: 'The solution should be something like "Delete these lines, and put in the function "Image_Watermark" here. So it can loop and edit trough each frame"'—that sounds about right. `Image_Watermark()` loads its source image from disk, and you probably don't want that. Maybe you could remove the `directory` parameter, change `filename` to `img` and pass in a frame directly? (I don't actually know if this will work, but it's the kind of thing we do while programming.)

Answer (score 0):

Put both functions in the same file (with the `Image_Watermark()` function declared above `process_image()`)

Edit the Image_Watermark function to get image from process_image instead of reading from a file:

```
def Image_Watermark(img):
    # use img passed as argument instead of reading from a file
    txt = Image.new('RGBA', img.size, (255,255,255,0))

    #Creating Text
    text = "WATERMARK EXAMPLE"
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 27)

    #Creating Draw Object
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)

    #Positioning of Text
    width, height = img.size
    # textwidth, textheight = d.textsize(text, font)
    # x=width/2-textwidth/2
    # y=height-textheight-300

    # Loop for Multiple Watermarks
    y=200
    for i in range(7):
        x=random.randint(0, width-300)
        y+=random.randrange(0,int(height/8), 19)+random.randint(0,100)
        draw.text((x,y), text, fill=(255,255,255, 75), font=font)

    #Combining both layers and return the new image
    watermarked = Image.alpha_composite(img, txt)
    return watermarked
```

Modify the process_image to the following:

```
def process_image(filename):
    original = Image.open(filename)

    new = []
    for frame_num in range(original.n_frames):
        original.seek(frame_num)
        new_frame = Image.new('RGBA', original.size)
        new_frame.paste(original)

        # call the watermark function instead of changing colors
        new_frame = Image_Watermark(new_frame)
        new.append(new_frame)



    new[0].save('Images/new.gif', append_images=new[1:], save_all=True, loop=0)
```

Call the `process_image(image_file_path)` function with the path to your file.

NOTE: I haven't tested if it's working. If you face any errors, please post them in a comment.